# getLocaleCode() by customer instead of store

Tags: magento2.3, cron, email-templates, out-of-stock

I am writing a module to send alert email to customer when a product is available. I have different email template with name like "alertmail EN", "alertmail FR"...

I can't do

```
$this->_store->getLocaleCode()
```

Because the mail is send by a cron. How can I get locale code by customer?

Comment: If you've got locales set at store level you can't. Customers are created at website level which means they can have multiple locales. I recommend you try and work out which locale customer last ordered from and go from there.

Comment: I just had to load customer_address_entity and get country_id

Comment: Makes sense. Same idea as my suggestion just different approach. Yours will be more efficient as more likely to have multiple orders but single address.